# Using numberPickerView with differant APIs

Tags: android

In some old APIs numberPickerView not Working.So if i use this view in a project manifest have to be set to higher.That means program not working in old APIs.So my questions are

1. Is there any View give same functionality in all APIs in Android?
2. Or is any way to show NumberPickerView in layout when run in latest APIs and show another view to enter numbers(Like EditText) in the place of NumberPickerView when running on older version?

Answer (score 0):

It was added in api 11. If you want pre-11, check this code:
https://github.com/michaelrnovak/numberpicker

You're welcome.